# SVG renders improperly after scroll and on different pages

Tags: html, css, svg

I have converted a badge/image from PNG to SVG in order to be able to re-use the asset in various sizes etc.

The problem is that depending on the specific webpage i'm embedding the SVG on, it either looks super crisp (as intended) or looks bad with some sort of anti-aliasing gone horribly wrong.
Even on the pages where the SVG looks crisp after load, I only have to scroll the page a bit until it looks horrible as well.

Please look at the screenshots below to see the exact difference on the BADGE (SVG):

[image: a busy cat]
[image: a busy cat]

It seems the browser only messes with the SVG right where the SVG meets the image behind it. The SVG is only slightly transparent in the gray center, so that should not be the cause of it. 
I have tested in Chrome, Edge, Safari which all do the same thing.

Does anybody know what might be the cause of this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a fix to what clearly seems to be a somehow undiscovered big bug in all modern browsers in regards to handling SVG through CSS as a background on an element overlapping another element with background/image.

The fix for my case was simply adding a background-color to the element. Since the element is completely round I can simply make a border-radius as well, so the background will never appear. 
If the element however was not a complete round circle, this would not be a workable fix.